# Java keycode to symbol

Tags: java

Обрабатываю нажатие клавиши с помощью функции keyDown, у которой параметр int

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode)
```

Нажав на клавиатуре клавишу A(англ), получил keycode 29, преобразую это число в char

```
symbol = (char)keycode;
```

получаю '\u001D', как на скриншоте ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как правильно получить букву А(англ) из keycode ?

Comment: какой символ?..

Comment: 29 символ это не буква A

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нажал клавишу A, хочу получить A

Comment: Ты нажал не `A`. либо не так определил.... у буквы А число 65 .........29 - GS (group separator)   http://ideone.com/OzKsw0